# Rock Paper Scissor Spock Lizard not working in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner to Python and I'm trying to understand what I did wrong. I'm having difficulty in the main function. I did most of my code correctly, except for the last part, in the main function. Can you advise on what went wrong?
    """ I am trying to create a game between the player and the computer to see who wins. The choices are 
    Rock, Paper, Scissors, Spock, and lizard. The winner is calculated by doing some arithemetic via the 
    modulus of 5 and creating some comparisons if True or False. Hope this helps """

```
def choice_to_number(choice):
    """Converts choice into number.
    Args:
        choice (str): Given game choice.
    Returns:
        int: Associated number for the given choice.
        """
    if choice == "Rock":        # This code converts a choice into a number.
        number = 0
    elif choice == "Spock":
        number = 1
    elif choice == "Paper":
        number = 2
    elif choice == "Lizard":
        number = 3
    elif choice == "Scissors":
        number = 4
    else:
        print("Invalid choice")
    return number

def number_to_choice(number):
    """Converts number into choice.
    Args:
        number (int): Given game number.
    Returns:
        str: Associated choice for the given number.
    """
    if number == 0:         # This code converts a number into a choice
        choice = "Rock"
    elif number == 1:
        choice = "Spock"
    elif number == 2:
        choice = "Paper"
    elif number == 3:
        choice = "Lizard"
    elif number == 4:
        choice = "Scissors"
    else: 
        print("Invalid number")
    return choice

def rpsls(player_number, comp_number):
    """Plays Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock game between player and computer.
    Args:
        player_number (int): Player's choice converted into number.
        comp_number (int): Computer's choice converted into number.
    Returns:
        bool: True if player wins the round; False if computer wins the round;
            None otherwise.
    """

    difference = (player_number - comp_number) % 5      
    if difference == 1 or difference == 2:
        result = True 
    elif difference == 3 or difference == 4:
        result = False
    else:
        result = None
    return result 

def main(argv):
    """Main function of the script.
    Args:
        argv (list): Contains command-line arguments passed to the script.
    Returns:
        int: Error code after execution (0 if OK).
    """
    error_code = 0
    # Get player's choice from command line.
    player_choice = input('Choose between "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors", "Lizard", or "Spock": >>> ')
    # Normalize player's input.
    player_choice = player_choice.lower().replace('"', '')
    # If player's choice is not valid, display error message and set error code.
    if player_choice not in ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'lizard', 'spock']:
        print('ERROR: Invalid choice!')
        print('Valid choices are "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors", "Lizard", or "Spock"')
        print('Try again...')
        error_code = 1
    # If error code has not been set, play the game.
    if error_code == 0:
        # Sample a random number between 0 and 4 for computer's choice.
        comp_number = random.randrange(0, 5)

        # Convert player's choice into number.
        player_number = choice_to_number(choice)

        # Convert computer's number into choice. (create comp_choice variable somewhere)
        comp_number = number_to_choice(number)

        # Play Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock 
        rpsls(player_number, comp_number)

        # Print out the choices of the player and the computer.
        print(player_choice)
        print(comp_choice)

        # Print out the result of the game round.

    if difference == 1 or difference == 2:
        print("Player wins!") 
    elif difference == 3 or difference == 4:
        print("Computer wins!")
    else: 
        print("It's a tie!")
    return error_code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    error_code = main(sys.argv[1:])
    print('[+] Terminated with code: ' + str(error_code))
    sys.exit(error_code)
```

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation? Also, can you tell us what `wrong` means?

Comment: yes, wrong means that the program did not execute properly. Meaning, that I was not able to act as the player or wait for the computer to make a choice to see who wins. Does that help?

Comment: You need to have a better look at `variable scope` and `functions and return values`: as Ori said in the answer, you are trying to use a variable which is not *there*. Maybe run again some simple tutorials on those topics.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  "did not execute properly" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the variable "difference" where it does not exists. Instead, use the return value from the "rpsls" function to see who won

Comment: Are you suggesting to simply substitute the "return result" variable instead of the "difference" in the main area to see who won. In other words, instead of saying "if difference == 1 or difference ==2, I should really be saying if result ==1 or 2, then print(player wins)?